# How can I implement extjs nested border layout?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, border-layout

I am working on an app that has 5 panels on top of each other. I want to use the `layout:'border'` so that I can take advantage of `split:true` config. Imagine a table with 5 rows each re-sizable and representing a panel.

Example:

```
frame: false,
width: 700,
border: false,
height: 600,
stateful: false,
layout: 'fit',
items: 
{
    layout: 'border',
    items:
    [
        {
            region: 'north',
            split: true,
            minWidth: 350,
            border: false,
            frame: false,
            layout: 'fit',
            title:'NNNNN',           
            margins: '0 0 0 0',
            items: []
        },
        {
            region: 'center',
            split: true,
            minWidth: 350,
            border: false,
            frame: false,
            layout: 'fit',
            title:'AAAAA',           
            margins: '0 0 0 0',
            items: 
            {
                layout: 'border',
                items:
                [
                    {
                        region: 'north',
                        .......
                    },
                    {
                        region: 'center',
                        .......
                    },
                    {
                        region: 'south',
                        ..........
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            region: 'south',
            split: true,
            minWidth: 350,
            border: false,
            frame: false,
            layout: 'fit',
            title:'CCCCCCCC',           
            margins: '0 0 0 0',
            items: []             
        }
    ]
}
```

I was also thinking about using `Resizer` but I have another problem here. This is the class I was using in ExtJs 3.4 and it was working:

```
Ext.define('myapp.ResizablePanel', 
{
    extend         : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias          : 'widget.reszpanel',

    handles        : 's',

    resizePanel: function()
    {
        this.syncSize();       
        this.updateLayout();
        if (this.layout) 
            this.doLayout(true, true);
    },

    onRender:function() 
    {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.resizer = new Ext.Resizable
        ({
            el: this.getEl(),
            handles: this.handles,
            minHeight: 120,
            maxHeight: 20000
        }).on("resize", this.resizePanel.bind(this));
    }
});
```

This was helpful, instead of `xtype: 'panel'`, I was using `xtype: 'reszpanel'` and everything was working fine until I updated the code to **ExtJS 4.2**. Now **`this.syncSize()`** function does not exist in Components and I do not know which newer function does this. That is way tried to implement using border layout.

**The problem is that when I have only one north, east, west, south, and center, everything is fine. But when I try to nest layouts, the code breaks. Any help? Thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple panels with region 'north', you just need to make sure to have exactly one center panel. Nesting panels is bad for performance, so you should try to avoid that if possible.

```
{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'north',
        title: 'North 1',
        split: true
    },{
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'north',
        title: 'North 2',
        split: true
    },{
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'north',
        title: 'North 3',
        split: true
    },{
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'center',
        title: 'Center'
    }]
}
```

Also refer to the notes on the [border layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Border) in the documentation.

Comment: ok, but the problem is now that it goes out of view, the last panel is falling out of screen height. Do you know ho to force it to add scrollbar so that all panels can be visible?

Comment: The problem is, that according to the docs the center panel will always have a flexible height, trying to fit the height of the container:
`Any child items with a region of north or south may be configured with either an initial height, or a Ext.layout.container.Box.flex value, or an initial percentage height string (Which is simply divided by 100 and used as a flex value). The 'center' region has a flex value of 1.`
You may try to create an empty center panel with `hidden: true` and only use north panels. You will probably also have to set `autoScroll: true`on the container.

Comment: you know what the biggest problem is? Lets say i have north panel with height 200, in that panel a grid will be rendered that can have height > 200. The problem is that I want the grid to have autoscroll in that case, but if i resize the panel, grid will also resize maybe untill its max height

Comment: Again, try to avoid nested panels where possible. A grid panel derives from the regular panel, so it inherits its behaviour. Couldn't you just set `region: north` on the grid instead of nesting it?